# How to unwrap a literal array retrieved using a 'get' expression in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a bunch of image icons associated with countries which I am using in a Mapbox layer to show rich country labels. I'm following [this example](https://codepen.io/rsh412/pen/PowGGpJ), which just inserts spaces between the icons.

However, I have 5 different icons. Any of them could appear, and I want to have the spacing always be consistent. So I don't want to use the "check if X is in an array" approach because I think I'd have to check twice, once for the icon and then again for the space. And it's a strange way to structure the data, anyway.

What I want is to pull a pre-composed set of images out of a variable, like so:

```js
        var countryWorkstreams = {
            'SEN': [
                ['image', 'fiscal'], ' ',
                ['image', 'health'], ' ',
                ['image', 'supply_chain']
            ]
        };
        map.on('load', function () {
            map.addLayer({
                'layout': {
                    'text-field': [
                        'format',
                        ['get', 'name_x'],
                        '\n',
                        ['get', ['get', 'iso_alpha3'], ['literal', countryWorkstreams]]
                    ],
                    // ...
                },
            });
        });
```

And this *ALMOST* works! Almost:

[image: Incorrect Senegal output]

I've tried just pulling the first item out with `'at'`, and that half works:

[image: halfway there]

But it still isn't interpreting the object values. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the followup!

If every country had the same icons and I didn't need to do this dynamically, I could make `'text-field'` look like this:

```js
'text-field': [
    'format',
    ['get', 'name_x'],
    '\n',
    ['image', 'health'], ' ',
    ['image', 'food'], ' ',
    ['image', 'fiscal'], ' ',
    ['image', 'management'], ' ',
    ['image', 'supply_chain']
],
```

In the case of Senegal, here's what that produces. Note the spaces:

[image: Senegal with icons and spaces]

I have succeeded in getting dynamic generation working without spaces using the "country codes in workstream arrays" approach, which looks like this:

```js
var managementWS    = ['GMB', 'GIN'];
var healthWS        = ['SEN', 'GMB'];
var supply_chainWS  = ['SEN', 'GIN'];
var fiscalWS        = ['SEN', 'MOZ'];
var foodWS          = ['GMB', 'GIN'];
// ...

'text-field': [
    'format',
    ['get', 'name_x'],
    '\n',
    ['case', ['in', ['get', 'iso_alpha3'], ['literal', managementWS]], ['image', 'management'], ''],
    ['case', ['in', ['get', 'iso_alpha3'], ['literal', healthWS]], ['image', 'health'], ''],
    ['case', ['in', ['get', 'iso_alpha3'], ['literal', supply_chainWS]], ['image', 'supply_chain'], ''],
    ['case', ['in', ['get', 'iso_alpha3'], ['literal', fiscalWS]], ['image', 'fiscal'], ''],
    ['case', ['in', ['get', 'iso_alpha3'], ['literal', foodWS]], ['image', 'food'], '']
],
```

Result:

[image: Senegal correct icons without spaces]

But I'd really prefer spaces between the icons. (If that could be done with CSS, that would be great! I guess I could add them to the 10x10 SVGs, make them 13x10 or something. But that feels really hacky.)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. Could you please include an example of the attributes of one feature, and also the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What's stopping you inserting spaces (`' ', `) as in your previous approach?